# How to fix UTF-8 encoding error with Russian words

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

My Perl script reads from an text file which contains mainly English ANSI words.
But there are Russian words sometimes, which I can not convert back to UTF-8.

See same example (the words in brackets are the English translations):

```
Êîìïîíåíò (Component)
Àâòîð (Author)
Ãýíäàëüô (Gandalf)
Äàòà ñîçäàíèÿ (Create date): 20-ìàé(may)-2003
Äàòà êîððåêöèè (Last correction Date): 25-ìàð(mar)-2003
Âåðñèÿ (Version): 0.92
Áëàãîäàðíîñòè (Thanks):
Íîâîå â (New in):
Ïîääåðæêà (Support)
Î÷åíü ìíîãî (Very much)
```

I've read the [UTF-8 Encoding Debugging Chart](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) and tried also the following

```
$s='Àâòîð';
from_to($s, "iso-8859-5","utf-8");  
print "$s\n";

my $s = Encode::decode( 'iso-8859-5', 'Àâòîð' );
from_to($s, "iso-8859-5","utf-8");  
print "$s\n";
```

I've tried also `cp1252` instead of `iso-8859-5`, but nothing helps.
I've tried also Encode::Guess, but the result is not helpful: `iso-8859-5 or cp1251 or koi8-r or iso-8859-1`.

Any idea how to convert 'Àâòîð' back to the Cyrillic text 'автор'?

Comment: Did you switch your codepage in the console to 65001? With `chcp 65001`, I get `Автор` as the output from: `perl -MEncode -wle "print encode('UTF-8',decode('Windows-1251',shift))" "Àâòîð"` , so your data is encoded as `Windows-1251` I guess.

Comment: Corion, how can I do that without using the console? I have to write the correct UTF-8 string to an .html file (with `<meta charset="utf-8">`).

Comment: Then output the file correctly: `open my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename or die "Couldn't write to $filename: $!"; print $fh decode('Windows-1251', ...);`

Comment: It works! Thank you. Why not post this as an answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tries, I get the expected output `Автор` when switching the (Windows) console code page to 65001 (UTF-8) and decoding the input data from `Windows-1251`:

```
perl -MEncode -wle "print encode('UTF-8',decode('Windows-1251',shift))" "Àâòîð"
```

This suggests that the input data is encoded as `Windows-1251` and decoding from that should give you the cyrrillic letters in Unicode. To output the data to a file, make sure you either set the encoding when opening the file (easiest) or `encode` each string to the target encoding on output (hard to keep track of):

```
my $octets = <$input_file>;

my $data = decode('Windows-1251', $octets;
open my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename
    or die "Couldn't write to $filename: $!";
print $fh decode('Windows-1251', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bytes sequence is 0xc0 0xe2 0xf2 0xee 0xf0. This is russian word 'author' in cp1251. Representation given by you can be get if your application assumes that this is cp1252 encoding. Now the question is here what codepage do you like to have? Or, what codepage needed to your application?

To read file in cp1251 in correct way you have to use construction like this:

```
open (my $tmp_h,"<:encoding(cp-1251)", $ARGV[0]) or die $!;
```

That allows perl to know what codepage do you use in your file. And then when you will read file into string it allows perl to correctly convert values from cp1251 to Perl's internal form (UTF-8) and use these string as you want without any problems.

For internal form perl set UTF8 flag you can check using Devel::Peek module.

I think, that using internal form also will give you chance to use any string operation correctly and will help avoid mistakes.

I would recommend to use "use utf8" pragma in our source code. Now, all literals in the source code will be threated as utf8 and automatically converted into internal form correctly. Now, we know that our source code is in UTF8 (and it would also better if with BOM, because detecting BOM usualy is the first thing different IDE and editor will typical do). Later, we can open other files in any encoding using "<:encoding(....)" construction get data from the web, from the databases and again make sure that data were converted into internal form correctly checking utf8 flag. Having all this, we would be able to work with all this data in one manner, correcly compare string, use regular expression and so on.

Comment: The user should not concern themselves with the internal form of the string. After decoding the input, it is just characters in the logical Perl representation. If you want to output them, you need to encode them to what the output expects, this is not related to the internal storage of the string.

Comment: @Grinnz, yes. Maybe 'users' should not concern (as it was said many times in many perl books), but 'developers' should know how it works behind the scene because otherwise you can get problems with string operations later.

Comment: By users, I am referring to Perl developers. If you are not writing XS code, concerning yourself with these details without a full understanding will inevitably lead to bugs, and this can be seen all over CPAN whenever anyone uses `is_utf8`.

Comment: @Grinnz, I heard this many times. But from the other hand, take a look at Perl modules for Windows OS where developers (users?) instead of Unicode version of Windows API use ANSI versions explicitly  adding 'A' at the end of each function. Other developers (users?) try to create Unicode files on NTFS or use COM and run into problems with these modules. To make it works, I think, they have only one option - take a look at source code of these modules and figure out how Perl works behind the scene with string. And it is not related to XS only.